# How to compute the eigenvalue condition number of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, condition-number

How to compute the eigenvalue condition number, $\kappa(4,A)$, of a matrix $A$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 1000 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

I am a bit stuck on how to proceed solving this problem
I know that the eigenvalue condition number equation is 
$κ(λ, A) = \|y\|\|x\|$.
But other than that, I am lost.

Comment: Where did you get that formula? It's in no way a condition number of an eigenvalue, which is actually defined by $\kappa_{\lambda}=\frac{\|x\|\|y\|}{|y^*x|}$, where $x$ and $y$ is, respectively, the right and left eigenvector associated with the (distinct) eigenvalue $\lambda$. It reflects the sensitivity of the eigenvalue w.r.t. perturbations of $A$ and essentially says that closer are $x$ and $y$ to be colinear, less sensitive the eigenvalue is (the least sensitivity happens when $x=y$ like for normal matrices).

Answer (score 0):

The right and left eigenvector can be obtained by computing the kernel of $X_{\lambda}$ and $X_{\lambda}^*$, where $X_{\lambda}=A-\lambda I$, which in this case is
$$
X_{4}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1000 & 2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So the right and left eigenvectors are given by
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}-2/1000\\1\end{bmatrix},\quad
y=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can verify that $X_{\lambda}x=0$ and $y^*X_{\lambda}=0$. So (using the (more) correct definition),
$$
\kappa_4\approx 500.
$$

Comment: Can you please give a reference for this formuls $k_\lambda$ ? My google search gives me only the BauerFike Theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @SrinivasK See, e.g., [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=l78PAQAAMAAJ), page 186.

Answer (score 0):

The condition number of an eigenvalue is actually $\frac{1}{y^*x}$ where x and y are right and left eigenvectors of your matrix with respect to the same eigenvalue. Before you apply the formula make sure you normalize your eigenvectors.